# Authenticating laravel users with passport JS

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, single-sign-on, passport.js

I have a few internal administration web tools. Some are written in [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), which has its own user management system, and some are semi-static web pages whose access is managed by [Apache `.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html). Obviously, this is a mess when I want to add or delete a user across all the system.

I am impressed with the elegance and simplicity of [Passport js](http://passportjs.org/), and I would like to use it as a single-sign-on solution for all of my internal sites.

The architecture I have in mind is:

[image: Architecture draft for an SSO solution]

Is there a way to use [Passport js](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate for [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), in a way that Laravel will know the user identity, but will not have to deal with password and authentication?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934364